# Google TV emulator hangs at google TV logo

Tags: android-emulator, google-tv

I'm trying to run the Google TV emulator on Ubuntu 12.04. The emulator starts, but hangs at a screen with a Google TV logo in the center of it. I connected via adb and the log is looping with the following messages:

```
I/CameraService( 1038): CameraService started (pid=1038)
I/AudioFlinger( 1038): AudioFlinger's thread 0x9bb5a78 ready to run
I/ServiceManager(  795): Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
I/ServiceManager(  795): Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
I/ServiceManager(  795): Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
I/ServiceManager(  795): Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
I/ServiceManager(  795): Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
D/AndroidRuntime( 1048): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 1048): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1048): CheckJNI is ON
E/dalvikvm( 1048): Bad heap size parameters (start=5242880, max=33554432, limit=100663296)
W/dalvikvm( 1048): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 1048): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
I/ServiceManager(  782): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(  782): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(  782): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(  782): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/Netd    ( 1050): Netd 1.0 starting
I/        ( 1049): ServiceManager: 0x8c6fed8
E/        ( 1049): Failed to switch to AID_MEDIA user, error -1
W/GoogleTVMediaApi( 1049): InitializeGTVMediaLibraries not implemented
W/AVAPIService( 1049): InstantiateAVAPIService not implemented
W/AudioHardwareInterface( 1049): Using stubbed audio hardware. No sound will be produced.
D/AudioHardwareInterface( 1049): setMode(NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new version of the emulator coming (extremely soon). In the interim you can check your AVD parameters. Mine are as follows:

```
hw.lcd.density=213
hw.keyboard.charmap=Emulator
sdcard.size=1G
skin.name=720p
skin.path=add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p
hw.cpu.arch=x86
abi.type=x86
vm.heapSize=256
hw.ramSize=1024
disk.dataPartition.size=128
image.sysdir.1=add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure which of the settings did it, but it starts now.

Answer (score 3):

The error arise because of "Bad heap size parameters ".
So resize the heap size:for me, I change heap size from 64 to 128.
In edit Android Virtual Device.

[image]